# PHP- how to pass variable with url in it from form to email program

Tags: php, email

I've been trying to figure this out all day. I'm trying to create a simple back-end email interface that will allow user to enter a few fields and then mail off to several email recipients. I have figured out most of it with the exception of being able to create a link in the message. Please help.
p.s. If there are suggestions for an entirely better way to do this, I'm open to them.Thank you, james.

my code:

```
$subj = "Try Our New Strawberry Bagels";
$chicken = $_POST['comments'];
$message = $chicken;



 // To send HTML mail, the Content-type header must be set
$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";

// Additional headers
$headers .= 'From: Birthday Reminder <birthday@example.com>' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Cc: birthdayarchive@example.com' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Bcc: birthdaycheck@example.com' . "\r\n";


 while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
 {
  $emails = $row['email'] . ",";
  mail($emails, $subj, $message, $headers);
 }



?>

<form action="testMail.php" method="post">
                            Name: <input type="text" name="fname" />
                             Age: <input type="text" name="age" />
                           Comment:<textarea name="comments" 
                           id="comments">      </textarea>
                            <input type="submit" />
                            </form>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're going to be spamming the heck out of the first whose name shows up in the database results. Most likely you'd want to move the `mail()` call OUTSIDE of your loop, you'll be sending to:

```
1st loop: a@example.com,
2nd loop: a@example.com, b@example.com,
3rd loop: a@example.com, b@example.com, c@example.com, 
etc...
```

You're also specifying in the mail headers that you're sending an HTML email, so just use html to specify the link.

```
$message = <<<EOL
<a href="http://example.com">Click here</a> for a strawberry bagel deal.
EOL;
```

Comment: Hi Marc. The first part of your response, when I move the mail() outside of the loop there are no emails sent out. The second part, I am trying to fill out a form and have the $_post come over and be used as a variable for the email message. I'm having a tough time having that variable contain a link, even with the content set up as HTML in the header. Thanks for the help